# Want to get current video duration in logcat. using exoplayer

Tags: android, android-logcat, exoplayer

I want to get current duration of video. I am using ExoPlayer(Exoplayer is used to play videos it is a video player) and i want to display current video playing duration. The method getCurrentDuration() is used to get current duration of video so I want to get that duration in log. That is why i code like this but it is not providing correct duration. I want that when video is playing and the current duration which is showing on seek bar should be displayed in log also.

```
for (long x=0;x<10000000;x++){

long position = mPlayer.getCurrentPosition();

Log.d(">>>>AdPopUp", Long.toString(position));
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, "it doesn't work".  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Comment: Always use `String.valueOf( i );` to convert any int,long,double value into String.

Comment: no one has answer of this?

Comment: Here is answer which explains how, using ExoPlayer and suspendCoroutine to return value.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/71708709/6039240

Answer (score 0):

There is a way:

```
private PlayerView videoView;

Log.i("video_duration", 
((TextView)videoView.findViewById(R.id.exo_duration)).getText().toString());
```

Remember not to call it immediately. It will return 00:00 instead use it inside a handler with postDelayed(Runnable, long millisec) like below:

```
videoView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
Log.i("video_duration", 
((TextView)videoView.findViewById(R.id.exo_duration)).getText().toString());
}
}, 2000);
```

However, you may use MediaMetadataRetriever:

```
MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
try {
     retriever.setDataSource(mContext, Uri.fromFile(file));
     String time = retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION);
     } catch (Exception ignored) {
    } finally {
        retriever.release();
    }
```