# How to get detail video information from URL in Android

Tags: java, android, url, video

I am looking for solution to get detail video information (like duration, video thumbnail...) from URL in Android?

Comment: It can't be taken until you load URL in your videoView OR you can receive this info from the server from where you are getting this url

Answer (score 3):

You are asking 2 different questions already answered here on StackOverflow.

To retrieve the video duration and other meta data, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36708456/5771029).

> Maybe you are looking for the [FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever](https://github.com/wseemann/FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever)
>
> **FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever** class provides a unified interface for the retrieving frame and metadata from an input media file.
>
> By using **METADATA_KEY_DURATION** constant of
>   *FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever* you can get the duration of your video.It will return the string to you then you can convert it into
>   LONG to get TIME.
>
> Here is the code you should use:
>
> ```
> FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever mFFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
> mFFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource("Your video url");
> String mVideoDuration =  mFFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever .extractMetadata(FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever .METADATA_KEY_DURATION);
> long mTimeInMilliseconds= Long.parseLong(mVideoDuration);
> ```
>
> if above still not work then use
>
> ```
> MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
> if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14)
>  retriever.setDataSource("Your video url", new HashMap<String, String>());
> else
>  retriever.setDataSource("Your video url");
> ```

To download the thumbnail, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32689023/5771029).

> Without downloading video you can generate thumbnail from below code:
>
> ```
> public static Bitmap retriveVideoFrameFromVideo(String videoPath) throws Throwable
> {
>     Bitmap bitmap = null;
>     MediaMetadataRetriever mediaMetadataRetriever = null;
>     try
>     {
>         mediaMetadataRetriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
>       if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14)
>           mediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(videoPath, new HashMap<String, String>());
>       else
>           mediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(videoPath);
>    //   mediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(videoPath);
>         bitmap = mediaMetadataRetriever.getFrameAtTime();
>     } catch (Exception e) {
>       e.printStackTrace();
>       throw new Throwable("Exception in retriveVideoFrameFromVideo(String videoPath)" + e.getMessage());
>
>     } finally {
>         if (mediaMetadataRetriever != null) {
>           mediaMetadataRetriever.release();
>         }
>     }
>     return bitmap;
> }
> ```

Both answers are for Android and does not require to download the whole video.

Comment: your answer (how to get video thumbnail from url) is giving this error ( status = 0x80000000 ). Why? 
I am trying to show video thumbnail from youtube.

Comment: @TarasStavnychyi Getting thumbnail from a video and from a video service like Youtube is very different. However, since this code supports MP4, you can use this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31566835/how-to-get-the-mp4-url-for-youtube-videos-using-youtube-v3-api to convert your Youtube URL to a mp4 url.

Answer (score 2):

try this to get video thumbnail from url

```
public static Bitmap retriveVideoFrameFromVideo(String videoPath)
        throws Throwable
{
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    MediaMetadataRetriever mediaMetadataRetriever = null;
    try
    {
        mediaMetadataRetriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14)
            mediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(videoPath, new HashMap<String, String>());
            else
                mediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(videoPath);
     //   mediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(videoPath);
        bitmap = mediaMetadataRetriever.getFrameAtTime();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new Throwable(
                "Exception in retriveVideoFrameFromVideo(String videoPath)"
                        + e.getMessage());

    }
    finally
    {
        if (mediaMetadataRetriever != null)
        {
            mediaMetadataRetriever.release();
        }
    }
    return bitmap;
}
```

credit goes to [@nilesh Rathod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44943575/how-to-create-thumbnail-of-video-url-form-server/44943830#44943830)