# how to get time duration of a HLS(.m3u8) video link in android?

Tags: android, video, http-live-streaming, duration

I have used this code but it does not work for HLS video...

```
MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
                            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14)
                                retriever.setDataSource("link" + movie.get(i).getMMovie(), new HashMap<String, String>());
                            else
                                retriever.setDataSource("link" + movie.get(i).getMMovie());
                            //retriever .setDataSource("Your video url");
                            String mVideoDuration2 = retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION);
                            long mTimeInMilliseconds2 = Long.parseLong(mVideoDuration2);
```

Please provide the solution for this..

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36708107/get-video-duration-from-url-in-android-app

Comment: here is link to answer solves this exact problem using exoplayer since other solutions didn't work https://stackoverflow.com/a/71708709/6039240